# How to install Multiple Extensions in Magento 1.9 using CLI

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

Ok , I realise there is an opinionated side of this question , but I don't want to do this wrong and break an install.

I am relatively new to Magento , and when I install an extension there is a process :  usually something like:

1. Copy the first directory to your magento root folder , then
2. Copy the second folder to the same place. I assume that this is so that
   magento doesn't try to install the extension while the files are
   still being copied.

I want to roll out a new site , and I want to do the whole thing with a script preferably rather than sitting there for ages installing extensions one by one.

Is it safe to copy ALL the extension files ( maybe 10 different extensions ) excluding their .xml files that go in /etc/modules - then copy the .xml files and run the whole lot by going to the site ( clearing cache ,  logging out etc ).

OR

Should I use a command line to install some other way? ( they are files so I won't get from the magento marketplace directly ) .

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes , you can copy all files excluding .xml files under app/etc to avoid any issues while copying all extension files.
- You can also do it other way like put the site in maintenance mode by adding `maintenance.flag` file in root folder. This way no user will be able to run your website .
- You can remove this flag file once all files are uploaded.
- You can also create tar.gz and upload on server and extract which will be faster way to upload extension files compare to uploading one by one using FTP.